# Writing to S3 from remote instance

Tags: amazon-s3

I would like to write files from a remote machine to Amazon S3. The machine I am working restricts outbound connections unless specified. I can have an ip whitelisted but from my understanding S3 uses a pool of addresses and they are not fixed. Not sure what my options are. Anything helps.

Thank you

Comment: The easiest would be to add the list of Amazon S3 IP ranges for your desired region to the whitelist (as per @prudviraj). Any other method would require infrastructure that relays your request to S3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Option 1 :**

Aws actually list the range of allowed ip's per each service

References  : 
1. https://ip-ranges.amazonaws.com/ip-ranges.json
2. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/aws-ip-ranges.html

You can write a script to download this range of ip's and automate the process of updating your security group accordingly

**option 2:**

If the remote resource (ec2-instance) you are using is also in AWS

Then you can create a new role (which will allow access to s3 operations ) and attach that role to your remote instance

Have not checked this option when we have restriction on outbound connection ,  but could be a better option if it works